# Not accepted license agreements for CMake 3.6.3155560

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I am in the process of creating build machine to automate APK generation. I have downloaded latest android SDK and NDK and installed gradle. But when I do `gradle assemble` I get this error:

> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
>     [CMake 3.6.3155560].

I have installed/updated **android-24,build-tools-24.0.1,extra-android-m2repository,platform-tools**. But on trying `android update sdk --no-ui --all -t android-sdk-license,android-sdk-preview-license`, got error:

> Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'android-sdk-license'
>
> Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'android-sdk-preview-license'
>
> Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
>            Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

I have `yum install cmake` but that didn't help either.

Please help guys.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem by installing CMake directly. I couldn't license transfer to UNIX build machine.

Here is how you install CMake using [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html#usage) :

```
sdkmanager "cmake;3.6.3155560"
```

Get the list of available packages by:

```
sdkmanager --list
```

Answer (score 0):

Option `-t` accept package names not licences.
Here is the official tutorial how to accept licenses: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Android toolchain uses its own cmake. That installed with `yum install cmake` doesn't matter.